# Why is a function called when it is assigned to a variable?

Tags: c, function

I've been working the exercises from K&R:  The C Programming Language and noticed something that confused me a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BLANK ' '

int c;
int d;

d = 0;
c = getchar();
```

When I execute this code, getchar() is called even though it's assigned to the variable 'c', yet 'c' was never called.  I also just changed the variable 'c' to

```
c = printf("hi");
```

which prints "hi" when the program is executed.  So, this behavior is consistent but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: "*this behavior is consistent*" - what behavior? Some functions return values. So this is assigning the return value to variable named `c`. It might be used later or it might not.

Comment: You aren't assigning the function to the variable, you are calling the function and assigning its result to the variable.

Comment: Why are you saying `c` was never "called"? `c` is a variable, what do you think that "calling" a variable is or does?

Comment: I understand now that it wasn't a good question but did you really need to jump down my throat?  @Joe cleared things up, so thank you.

Comment: Don't take it personally.

Comment: @Schultzie67 I'm sorry about the other comments left here. I think it was a good question on a few key points - it made the core question clear, and it included a sample program that I could reference throughout my answer. I don't think that a question falling under introductory language rules makes it bad, and I don't think the critical comments were warranted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fairly standard for many imperative programming languages<sup>1</sup> - the statement `c = getchar();` means that the program should, *at that point in time*, invoke `getchar()` (which reads a character from the standard input, waiting if necessary), and store its return value to some storage location that was allocated for the variable called `c`. The fact that you do not use `c` later is irrelevant (note that I use the word "use" and not the word "call" as you did; we do not call variables).

In your second example with `printf`, you have a function with a very visible side effect (printing to the console). Again, that side effect occurs when the statement `c = printf(...)` is executed, *not* when `c` is later used.

You'll also notice that in the following snippet, getchar is only called once, regardless of whether you use the value of `c` zero times, once, twice, or even more:

```
int c;
c = getchar();
printf("%c", c);
printf("%c", c);
```

<sup>1</sup> There are other families of languages, where you indeed do have variables that refer to computation that hasn't happened yet. Such a thing often occurs in functional languages in various scenarios, but C does not fall into that category.

<sup>2</sup> This question deals with two functions that have side effects and/or are impure. If you study the language more deeply and start learning about things like concurrent programming or compiler design, you should know that these rules apply to *visible* effects, such as the side effects you observed. Compilers and optimizers often can and will simplify/reorder the program internally to make it more efficient, but they must ensure that the visible effects of the program remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you had `c = &getchar` (but then `c` would have to be of type `int (*)(void)` and not `int`), it would be as you described, because then you'd save a function pointer to `getchar` in `c`. You'd then be able to do `c()` later on.

But you have `getchar()` here which is already a function *invocation*! So the function gets called (using operator `()`) at this line, and the result is stored in `c`.